# Gradle Wrapper - how to use different distributionUrls for Local vs CI builds?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I want to use distributionUrl pointing to "ALL" for local builds, but "BIN" for CI builds.

Let's say I run Gradle Wrapper locally like this:

```
./gradlew test
```

And my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file (which is checked-in to VCS) points to "ALL" distribution:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip
```

Is there a parameter I can pass to `./gradlew test` to change distribution-type to BIN?

Comment: It seems that `--gradle-distribution-url` might be helfpul. However it's used when wrapper is generated. Have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper). It seems that you need to regenerate gradle wrapper on CI and then use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
sed -i 's/all.zip/bin.zip/g' gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

before running `./gradlew` on CI.

Imperfect, but it works for me.